# How to write earlier statement in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I was looking at prolog progrm and was unable to understand the following

```
earlier(X, _, [X|_]).
earlier(_, Y, [Y|_]) :- !, fail.
earlier(X, Y, [_|T]) :- earlier(X, Y, T).
```

Can anyone explain what does it mean??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, `earlier(X, Y, Zs)` is apparently supposed to check whether the element `X` appears earlier than the first occurrence of `Y` in the list `Zs`. It kind of does this:

```
?- earlier(a, b, [a, b, c, d]).
true ;
false.

?- earlier(b, d, [a, b, c, d]).
true ;
false.
```

With peculiar handling if the second argument is not in the given list:

```
?- earlier(a, not_in_list, [a, b, c, d]).
true ;
false.
```

How does this work? The first clause says that if `X` is the head of the list, then `X` appears earlier in the list than anything, represented by the anonymous variable `_`. The second clause says that if `Y` is the head of the list, then nothing (`_` in first argument position) is before `Y`. In this case, the predicate fails and uses a cut to avoid finding spurious solutions. The third clause just recurses on the list of neither the first nor second clauses applied.

Due to the cut, this definition is not very declarative, and some interesting uses don't work as one might expect:

```
?- earlier(X, Y, Zs).
Zs = [X|_G947] ;
false.

?- earlier(a, b, Zs).
Zs = [a|_G923] ;
false.

?- earlier(X, Y, [a, b, c, d]).
X = a ;
false.
```

The last case, in particular, might be interesting for some use cases. Here is a more declarative version:

```
earlier_than(X, Y, Zs) :-
    append(InitialPart, [X | _Rest], Zs),
    notmember_of(Y, InitialPart).

notmember_of(_X, []).
notmember_of(X, [Y|Xs]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    notmember_of(X, Xs).
```

You can use this to enumerate solutions more nicely:

```
?- earlier_than(X, Y, Zs).
Zs = [X|_G947] ;
Zs = [_G1162, X|_G1166],
dif(Y, _G1162) ;
Zs = [_G1254, _G1257, X|_G1261],
dif(Y, _G1257),
dif(Y, _G1254) ;
Zs = [_G1346, _G1349, _G1352, X|_G1356],
dif(Y, _G1352),
dif(Y, _G1349),
dif(Y, _G1346) .

?- earlier_than(a, b, Zs).
Zs = [a|_G923] ;
Zs = [_G1086, a|_G1090],
dif(_G1086, b) ;
Zs = [_G1169, _G1172, a|_G1176],
dif(_G1169, b),
dif(_G1172, b) ;
Zs = [_G1252, _G1255, _G1258, a|_G1262],
dif(_G1252, b),
dif(_G1255, b),
dif(_G1258, b) .

?- earlier_than(X, Y, [a, b, c, d]).
X = a ;
X = b,
dif(Y, a) ;
X = c,
dif(Y, b),
dif(Y, a) ;
X = d,
dif(Y, c),
dif(Y, b),
dif(Y, a) ;
false.
```

Personally, if the specification permits, I would also add a `member(Y, Rest)` to the definition of `earlier_than/3`. This makes things even nicer:

```
?- earlier_than(X, Y, Zs).
Zs = [X, Y|_G950] ;
Zs = [X, _G949, Y|_G953] ;
Zs = [X, _G949, _G952, Y|_G956] .

?- earlier_than(a, b, Zs).
Zs = [a, b|_G926] ;
Zs = [a, _G925, b|_G929] ;
Zs = [a, _G925, _G928, b|_G932] .

?- earlier_than(X, Y, [a, b, c, d]).
X = a,
Y = b ;
X = a,
Y = c ;
X = a,
Y = d ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
X = b,
Y = d ;
X = c,
Y = d ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, please "accept" it by clicking the check mark next to it.